# Show tree of directory of public repository

Tags: git, github, repository

I'm trying to compose a tree of a public GitHub repositories in order to make a research on a specific packages. I tried with GHTorrent but it doesnt allow packages names. 
So, how I can get packages/folders names or a tree of a public repository?

Comment: Can you clone it?

Comment: Using [Github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/): [Get a tree recursively](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/#get-a-tree-recursively).

Comment: I cant clone it, because clone all public repositories requires a large amount of space (in order of TB).

Comment: I'll try GitHub API to get a tree recursively, thank you.